# Pandas read_csv - Error tokenizing data after modifying Excel .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, character-encoding

I have a CSV dataset for an ML classifier. It has 2 columns and looks like this:

[image]

But this dataset is very dirty, so I decided to open it with Excel, remove "dirty" words, and save it as a new CSV file and train my ML classifier on it.

But after I saved it in Excel (using `,` separator and also tried `, UTF-8`), and when trying `pd.read_csv` on it, it gives me this error:

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 4, saw 5
```

Then I tried to use `sep=';'` with `read_csv`, and it worked, but now all Russian characters are replaced with strange symbols:

[image]

Can somebody explain please how to repair "question"-symbols from Russian characters? `encoding='UTF-8'` gives this error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 22: invalid continuation byte
```

This is what the first file looks like (not modified Excel `.csv` file):

[image]

When I open second file (modified):

[image]

Comment: Could you upload the CSV file to GitHub or pastbin or something like that?

Comment: @user17242583, yes, here is dropmefiles dataset and dataset1 are first and modified datasets https://dropmefiles.com/ku24y

Comment: @user17242583, also added photos of excel opened files

Comment: I'm afraid you corrupt the file when you save it in Excel. Perhaps the encoding you're saving it in is too simple, so it corrupts the files.

Comment: @user17242583, oh my god the programming is very crazy thing. The week ago or later i saved 2 files with different saving methods (,) and (UTF-8 with ,) and now i have just used 'read_csv' with second file that was saved with (UTF-8 with ,) and using 'encode='UTF-8'. It works fine now. Oh my god xDD i am dumb, thank you for help anyway)

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad to help. I though the data was corrupted, but actualy, it turns out that there are many, many encodings, and some of them happened to work!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the file with either `ptcp154` or `kz1048` encodings. They seem to work.